# SMTP connection lost after final dot on exim4 Debian

Tags: linux, debian, smtp, exim

I have an SV3C camera (very cheap MIC) that has a poor SMTP implementation

I'm using `exim4` to send mail from it. Although the connection test says *succeeded* my `exim4` log shows:

```
2017-10-21 11:17:08 1e5vWO-0007JY-3X SMTP connection lost after final dot H=sv3ccam1.local (RT-IPC) [192.168.1.81] P=esmtp
2017-10-21 11:17:15 1e5vWV-0007KC-L2 SMTP connection lost after final dot H=sv3ccam1.local (RT-IPC) [192.168.1.81] P=esmtp
```

...over and over again. I've read the documentation for `exim4`, read all results on google, etc. Cannot find a way to turn this off on `exim4`.  Since it's an internal mail relay and not accessible from anything but cameras on an internal network, I don't care about having it safeguarded from SPAM, abuse, etc. since it is not accessible by those things.

Any `exim` experts out there know how to change this in the config or work around it?

I guess it's important to note that the email does not come through to the destination and `exim4` deletes it from the queue.

Let me know if you need more info and thanks in advance for your help.